# cannot understand the following code in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

the following is declared inside the `@interface` of another class... I don't understand the syntax and what it is trying to say

```
@interface someclass:NSObject
....
@end

@interface NSObject (HSRequestClassDelegate)

-(void) finishedWithData:(HSRequest *) request data:(NSMutableData *) data;
-(void) failedWithError:(HSRequest *) request error:(NSError *) error;
-(void) noConnection:(HSRequest *) request;

@end
```

The name of the above file is someclass.h?
what does the line `@interface NSObject (HSRequestClassDelegate)` mean?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a definition of an informal protocol. Prior to protocols being introduced, protocols were defined as a category on `NSObject`.

Answer (score 2):

That's called a "[category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html)" in cocoa.